# Type 'FacebookOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider' (Ionic 5 - Facebook ionic native)

Tags: angular, facebook, ionic-framework

I suddenly started to receive these errors after I restarted my ionic app:

> TS2322: Type 'FacebookOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.   Type 'FacebookOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'TypeProvider': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.

`app.module`

```js
// More imports above
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx'; <--- I triple checked that this is the correct import

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // List of components here
    ],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        // List of modules here
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        IsLoggedInGuard,
        FCM,
        IsNotLoggedInGuard,
        Facebook, // <----- Error here
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

And where I inject the reference:

> 'Facebook' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Facebook'?

`login.component.ts`

```js
// More imports above
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    public datosBasicos: Basicos;
    public colores: Color = new Color();

    constructor(
        public loginService: SessionService,
        private router: Router,
        private fb: Facebook, // <----- Error here
        private platform: Platform,
        private colorService: ColorService,
        public basicosService: BasicosService
    ) {
    }

    async ngOnInit() {
        // this.autologinIfPreview();
        await this.loginService.loginAnonimo();        
        this.colores = this.colorService.color;
        this.datosBasicos = await this.basicosService.findDatosBasicos().pipe(first()).toPromise();
    }

    public async loginFacebook() {
        const fbResponse = await this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email']).then(); // Because of previous error, this isn't working at all

        await this.loginService.loginFacebook(fbResponse);

        this.router.navigate(['/main/home']).then();
        // await this.loginService.loginFacebook();

    }
```

If I add "typeof Facebook" this error appears at runtime:

> This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 2 of the parameter list is invalid.
> This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

This error is driving me crazy, I was able to actually build the ionic app and perform a login with Facebook before. I tried to reinstall the plugin and types and change the version of them without any success.

Comment: this.fb.login([...]); remove user_friends scope since it will cause login to fail when making release build and deploying to app store and play store, just use public_profile and email scopes. This is not related to the error but its a furure error. And for the loginFacebook function you can copy the same content as in ionic framework docs about the plugin ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got it!

Somewhere else in my application, I was using this:

`session.service.ts`

```js
import {FacebookLoginResponse} from '@ionic-native/facebook'; // <--- Here!!! should be: '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx'


public async loginFacebook(facebookResponse: FacebookLoginResponse): Promise<User> {
     if (facebookResponse) {
         const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookResponse.authResponse.accessToken);

         const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
         return userCredential.user;
     }
     return null;
}
```

Hope this helps someone, this bug was a time waster